# How to fix the following unexpected result of a bevel along a path?

Tags: modeling, bevel

I have the following situation, where the straight line represents a path I want to extrude the half-round curve along:

[image]

My approach was to apply a 'bevel', by selecting the straight line curve, then under 'Geometry', 'Bevel', I've selected the other curve, which results in:

[image]

There are two problems here, first I expect the resulting mesh to be flipped (not a big problem), but more importantly, the extrusion is much wider than the input curve for the bevel operation, which is unwanted. Is the bevel tool the way to achieve an extrusion like this? Am I using the bevel tool in the wrong way? Are there more intuitive ways to achieve what I want? As you can tell, I'm completely lost here.

*Update:* I realize there is a much simpler way; I've converted the rounded curve to a mesh, and then used extrusion on the face which gets me what I want. Still, I'm interested in the answer to the question...

Comment: Try applying the scale on both objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bevel profile comes from object data, not from the scene. That's mean that object rotations are ignored and points comes from local coordinates. So I expect that you have flipped your profile so that it points down, while in local space it still points up. The same thing is related to width. If you rotate profile so that it will be perpendicular to path, you will see that it perfectly match